# Create SQLite Table in Different Class & Perform CRUD operation in Different Class

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I Have Total 5 Table in SQLite database So if i create a all table in **`DatabaseHalper.class`** and perform all **CRUD((Create, Read, Update and Delete))** Operation in this class then this is look like a **Big Data**

***`Table Is Like: Company, Contact, ToDo`. etc***

- So 1st I Want to create a multiple table in **`DatabaseHalper.class`**
- 2nd Create a another class Like using Table Name **`ComapnyDB.class`**
  In this Class i want to Perform CRUD operation for a **`Company`** Table also All query perform for Company table
- 3rd same for **`Contact`** table. Create table in **`DatabaseHalper.class`**
  and create a new class like **`Contact.class`** in this class perform all CURD operation and perform other operation

**So this way my code was Divided in different different class**

- For Example Below class is my **`DatabseHalper.class`** and in this class i'll create a Database Tables.

**`DatabaseHalper.class`**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Logcat tag
    private static final String LOG = "DatabaseHelper";

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";

    //Tables Name
    private static final String COMPANY = "company";
    private static final String CONTACTS = "contacts";
    private static final String EVENT = "event";
    private static final String TODO = "todo";
    private static final String USER = "user";

    // Common column names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";

    //Companies Table Column Name
    private static final String KEY_COMPANY_ID = "CompanyId";
    private static final String KEY_COMPANY_REFERENCE_ID = "ReferenceId";
    private static final String KEY_COMPANY_NAME = "CompanyName";
    private static final String KEY_COMPANY_WEBSITE = "CompanyWebsite";
    private static final String KEY_COMPANY_EMAIL = "CompanyEmail";
    private static final String KEY_COMPANY_PHONE_HOME = "CompanyPhoneHome";
    private static final String KEY_COMPANY_PHONE_PRIMARY = "CompanyPhonePrimary";
    private static final String KEY_COMPANY_ADDRESS1 = "CompanyAddress";
    private static final String KEY_COMPANY_ADDRESS2 = "CompanyAddressSecondary";
    private static final String KEY_COMPANY_CITY = "CompanyCity";
    private static final String KEY_COMPANY_STATE = "CompanyState";
    private static final String KEY_COMPANY_ZIP = "CompanyZip";
    private static final String KEY_COMPANY_COUNTRY = "CompanyCountry";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Table Create Statements
    // Todo table create statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_COMPANY = "CREATE TABLE "
            + COMPANY + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_COMPANY_ID + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_COMPANY_REFERENCE_ID + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_COMPANY_NAME + " VARCHAR,"
            + KEY_COMPANY_WEBSITE + "VARCHAR,"
            + KEY_COMPANY_EMAIL + "VARCHAR,"
            + KEY_COMPANY_PHONE_HOME + "VARCHAR,"
            + KEY_COMPANY_PHONE_PRIMARY + "VARCHAR,"
            + KEY_COMPANY_ADDRESS1 + "VARCHAR,"
            + KEY_COMPANY_ADDRESS2 + "VARCHAR,"
            + KEY_COMPANY_CITY + "VARCHAR,"
            + KEY_COMPANY_STATE + "VARCHAR,"
            + KEY_COMPANY_ZIP + "INTEGER,"
            + KEY_COMPANY_COUNTRY + "VARCHAR" + ")";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_COMPANY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + COMPANY);
    }
}
```

Now I'll Create **`CompanyDB.class`** For a **CURD** Operation But How to i access **`DatabaseHelper.class`** In **`Company.class`**.

Thanks In Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is an example of splitting tables away from the DatabaseHelper :-

#### ContactDB.java

```
public class ContactDB {

    public static final String TBNAME = "contact";
    public static final String COL_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COL_NAME = "contact_name";
    public static final String COL_EMAIL = "contact_email";

    public static String getTableCreatSQL() {
        return "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBNAME + "(" +
                COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                COL_NAME + " TEXT," +
                COL_EMAIL + " TEXT" +
                ")";
    }

    public static long addContact(SQLiteDatabase db, String contact_name, String contact_email) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_NAME,contact_name);
        cv.put(COL_EMAIL,contact_email);
        return db.insert(TBNAME,null,cv);
    }

    public static Cursor getAllContacts(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        return db.query(TBNAME,null,null,null,null,null,COL_NAME + " ASC," + COL_EMAIL + " ASC");
    }
}
```

#### CompanyDB.java

```
public class CompanyDB {

    public static final String TBNAME = "company";
    public static final String COL_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String  COL_NAME = "company_name";


    public static String getTableCreateSQL() {
         return "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBNAME + "(" +
                 COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                 COL_NAME + " TEXT" +
                 ")";
    }

    public static long addCompany(SQLiteDatabase db, String company_name ) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_NAME,company_name);
        return db.insert(TBNAME,null,cv);
    }

    public static Cursor getAllCompanies(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        return  db.query(TBNAME,null,null,null,null,null,COL_NAME + " ASC");
    }
}
```

#### DBHelper.java (Database helper)

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "mydatabase";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    private static SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CompanyDB.getTableCreateSQL());
        db.execSQL(ContactDB.getTableCreatSQL());
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

#### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Cursor mAllContacts;
    Cursor mAllCompanies;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SQLiteDatabase mDB = new DBHelper(this).getWritableDatabase();

        CompanyDB.addCompany(mDB,"mycompany");
        ContactDB.addContact(mDB,"Fred","Fred@email.com");
        ContactDB.addContact(mDB,"Bert","bertbloggins@bloggings.moc");

        mAllCompanies = CompanyDB.getAllCompanies(mDB);
        while (mAllCompanies.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d("COMPANY",
                    "Company Name = " +
                            mAllCompanies.getString(
                                    mAllCompanies.getColumnIndex(
                                            CompanyDB.COL_NAME
                                    )
                            )
            );
        }
        Cursor mAllContacts = ContactDB.getAllContacts(mDB);
        while (mAllContacts.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d("CONTACT",
                    "Contact Name = " +
                    mAllContacts.getString(
                            mAllContacts.getColumnIndex(
                                    ContactDB.COL_NAME
                            )
                    ) +
                    " Email = " +
                            mAllContacts.getString(
                                    mAllContacts.getColumnIndex(
                                            ContactDB.COL_EMAIL
                                    )
                            )
            );
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mAllCompanies.close();
        mAllContacts.close();

    }
}
```

- This will add a company and 2 contacts (each time that it is run), retrieve the companies and contacts from the database and write the details to the log.

Output would be lime (first run) :-

```
04-02 09:09:42.556 1497-1497/so49607475_splittableclasses.so49607475_splittableclasses D/COMPANY: Company Name = mycompany
04-02 09:09:42.556 1497-1497/so49607475_splittableclasses.so49607475_splittableclasses D/CONTACT: Contact Name = Bert Email = bertbloggins@bloggings.moc
    Contact Name = Fred Email = Fred@email.com
```

Comment: In your example you create a Table in **`DatabaseHelper.class`** and then Create a two class Like **`CompanyDB.class`** OR **`ContactDB.class`** For Perform CRUP operation Right **?**

Comment: What happens is when you instantiate the DBHelper it will open or create the database. If the latter then both tables are created by getting the SQL from the respective CompanyDB or ContactDB classes via the getTableCreatSQL method for the class. The `addCompany` / `addContact` are I believe what people call CRUD as possibly are the `getAllContacts` and `getAllCompanies` methods.

Comment: But I'll create Tables and fields in **`DatabaseHalper.class`** and Perform CURD Operation in `ContactDB.class` / `CompanyDB.class`
but in your example create a table in `DatabaseHalper.class` and you declare a Field in this two class  `ContactDB.class` / `CompanyDB.class` 
so i want to Create a Table and declare a Field in `DatabaseHalper.class` and other class i want to perform only CURD operation

Comment: Thank you So much for this help i follow this example and it's work well also i find my solution without any document **Thank For your Answer** @MikeT